# android tablet - run specific app (web-app) strict

Tags: android, tablet

i want to take tablet (some cheap chinese one) and run specific app on it (actually it is web page, so i need browser).
for example, i need the tablet to run the browser on "http://cnn.com" and thats it.
disable all buttons and disable all the other functions.. (power on the device to the specific page).

how can i perform this? i tried to read about building specific ROM but it looks like it will not be easy, especially with cheap unknown tablets..

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you're after a 'kiosk mode'. Do a search for that and you should find some old SO questions to help you out.

Comment: i will read about it and update here. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you NigelK.
i find some tutorials for kiosk app.
the best solution is to run service in parallel that check the app is in the foreground.

please find the following tutorial:
http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/forum/threads/android-kiosk-mode-tutorial.10839/